# Добавить условие в метод

Tags: kotlin

Есть рабочий метод:

```
fun getTimeFromLastPinInput(): Long {
    return DateTime.now().millis - PreferenceRepository.getLastPinInputTime()
}
```

Пробую добавить следующее условие перед ним:

```
    if (DateTime.now().millis >= PreferenceRepository.getLastPinInputTime())
```

Студия предлагает добавить ещё один return(а если более точней удалить тип возвращаемый Long), не знаю как правильно его добавить так, чтобы метод не ломался.

Comment: ну правильно, оно вернёт если условие тру, а если фолс, то что ему возвращать? Нужно дефолтное значение какое-то сделать если условие неверно. Если не секрет: зачем использовать сразу котлин ?

Comment: @A-Z а какое то это какое? можно чуть поконкретней?
по поводу котлина, проект на котлине, поэтому собственно и на нём.

Comment: Как должен вести себя Ваш(!) метод, если вышеприведенное условие не будет соблюдаться? Сторонние люди не смогут ответить на данный вопрос.

Comment: @post_zeew ну а тогда как добавить корректно условие, чтобы DateTime.now().millis всегда было больше второго аргумента?

Comment: Никак. При выполнении заданного условия, возвращаемое значение будет неотрицательным. В противном случае можете возвращать отрицательное значение, например, минус единицу.

Comment: @post_zeew почему оно будет неотрицательным? чисто гипотетически оно может быть отрицательным, так как в качестве второго аргумента, я могу сохранять любые значения, равзе нет?

Comment: `a >= b <=> a - b >= 0`.